# ElementTree XML-Parser, additional hyperlink written into tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xml.etree

Parsing out tags of an .XML file gives additional hyperlink.

I'm trying to read data of a .mzXML file, that is build like a common .XML file. 
Printing out the tags is giving me an additional hyperlink of the classification beyond in the "header".

my mzXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<mzXML xmlns="http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1 http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1/mzXML_idx_2.1.xsd">
<msRun scanCount="1">
```

my python code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.mzXML')
root = tree.getroot()

print(root[0].tag)
```

the expected output is

```
msRun
```

the actual output is

```
{http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1}msRun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem in a "non-canonical" way. I tried to run your code with a little changes (i suggest you to learn and use lxml, is more powerfull than the standard python library for xml, and if you're going to use big and nested files you should consider it):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.mzXML')
root = tree.getroot()

print(root[0])
```

The result was

```
<Element {http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1}msRun at 0x7ff99afa9e88>
```

So, the full tag of your file is, as expected, `{http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1}msRun`. You can use, if this problem is reiterated in the dataset, the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.mzXML')
root = tree.getroot()
tag = root[0].tag.split('}')

print(tag[1])
```

And your output will be as expected. This is a very specific solution, but if all the dataset is affected by this problem, it could be a solution.